# how to reference a method from within an object

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I need to call the object showMe() method from a child object, when debugging the this does not recognize the showMe() method.

How can I reference an object method from within the method ???

code follows -

```
 function myObj(n) {
        this.name = n;
        this.frame = $('<div />');
        var subFrame = $('<div />');
        subFrame.on("click", function () {


            **//how do I reference this.showName() from here ?**


        });
        this.frame.append(subFrame);
        this.showName = function (nn) {
            alert(nn);
        };
    }

    $(function () {
        var a = new myObj("Test");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do this is to define `var that = this`, and refer to `that` in the function body.

You could also use `bind`, but then you give up the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just pass a reference to the object into `on()` as data,

```
function myObj(n) {
    this.name = n;
    this.frame = $('<div />');
    var subFrame = $('<div />');

    subFrame.on("click", {myObj : this}, function (e) {

        e.data.myObj.showName();

    });

    this.frame.append(subFrame);
    this.showName = function (nn) {
        alert(nn);
    };
}

$(function () {
    var a = new myObj("Test");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0yon9czq/)